# What happened to the bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

The question [Include a line break in algorithmic while maintaining indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33979/include-a-line-break-in-algorithmic-while-maintaining-indentation) was offered a bounty by [@BorisBukh](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1630/boris-bukh) after not receiving enough attention:

[image]

The drop in reputation on @BorisBukh's account reflects this:

[image]

This bounty has long since expired, with nothing awarded.

My [original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33995/5764) was updated to include a "less cumbersome" alternative. Could this have been a problem? That is, should I have submitted a new/separate answer in order to be granted this bounty?

My question stems from some of the answers to [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perusing the link you provided, it seems that the OP would have been allowed to award the bounty to an "old" answer (i.e., one that existed at the time the bounty was created). However, in case the OP doesn't choose any answer, half the bounty will be awarded automatically to the highest-scoring *"new"* answer with a score of at least 2. So yes, this is a case where submitting a separate answer would have increased your chances to receive at least part of the bounty.

Possible refinement of the bounty system: Take "old" answers into account for "automatic" partial bounty awards if they are edited after the bounty starts and then improve their score by at least 2.

Comment: So this was a bounty that was just lost since it wasn't assigned manually?

Comment: @Werner I'd assume so: the same thing happens if no-one answers a question with a bounty.